# "На балконе" или "в балконе"?

Tags: орфография, предлоги

Как правильно: "на балконе" или "в балконе"?

Answer (score 1):

Чаще всего правильно будет "на балконе": сидеть на балконе, выйти на балкон, места на балконе и т.п. В старых книгах изредка встречается "в балконе", особенно если разговор о театральном балконе. Например, "в балконе 25 мест".

В некоторых случаях правильно будет "в балконе". Например, на вопрос: "Вам что, балкон не понравился?", нельзя ответить: "Да дело не на балконе...".

Answer (score 0):

В поддержку ответа grizzly (@grizzly).  В словаре находим только "на балконе":

> [БАЛКОН](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD), -а; м. [итал. balcone]. 1. Выступающая из стены здания площадка с перилами, сообщающаяся с внутренним помещением. Выйти, выставить что-л. **на б.** Вид с балкона. Дом без балконов. 2. Верхний или средний ярус в зрительном зале театра, кинотеатра. Первый ряд балкона. Получить места **на балконе**. <Балконный, -ая, -ое. Б-ая дверь. Б-ые перила. Балкончик, -а; м. Уменьш.-ласк. (1 зн.).

В Нацкорпусе нашлось только одно вхождение типа "где? - в балконе", оно касается театрального балкона и датируется 1867 годом:

> Она даже и в театр раза два сводила ее с собою, сводила, конечно, не в литерную ложу, как некогда генеральша фон Шпильце, а **в балкон** ― попроще и подешевле. [В. В. Крестовский. Петербургские трущобы. Книга о сытых и голодных. Ч. 6 (1867)]  [омонимия не снята]  ←…→